# how to know Datatable is already subscribed?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset, system.data.datatable

How to know that DataTable is already subscribed to OnRowChanged or OnColumnChanged events ?
I am facing a issue with many notifications in my app ? so I wanted to put a check and want to subscribe table only once ??

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the declaring class it is deliberately tricky to see what is subscribed, since that is generally not something you need to know.

Depending on the scenario, *either* get very good at tracking when you subscribe, or simply unsubscribe *first* (which does nothing if you aren't subscribed):

```
foo.OnSomeEvent -= SomeHandler;
foo.OnSomeEvent += SomeHandler;
```

As long as the **handler and target-instance** (for non-static handlers) is the same this will:

- if subscribed, the net result is that you are still subscribed afterwards
- if not subscribed, the net result is that you end up subscribed